# Analyze data in 2 tables based on date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables in Power BI that look like this:

[Deals Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIjK.png)

[Activities Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU8Il.png)

What I need is to compare the 2 tables and allocate to each activity the corresponding stage resulting in something like this:

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOia5.png)

It is OK for me if the stage column is brought into the Activities table or a new table is created or any other solution you see.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the rules to get the stage number ?
It depends of the date of the update in the first table ?

Comment: Exactly. The data is taken automatically from Pipedrive. When a new data row enters PowerBI, I already have a stage for it. Then, when the stage changes, the column "Stage_change_date" is updated.

In the 2nd table, I have the date when a certain activity is marked as done. So I need a formula that will bring the stage from the first table to the 2nd one, based on the "marked_as_done" date in relationship with the stage update date.